# Not able to get the google map bounds

Tags: google-maps, jquery-plugins

I am using [geocomplete](http://ubilabs.github.com/geocomplete/) to load the map. My question is, is there any way to get the bound of the map. I used to use

```
var bounds = results[0].geometry.bounds;
```

to get the bound is not working here, my code is given below

```
  $("#textfield").geocomplete({
              map: ".map_canvas",
              details: "form",
              types: ["geocode", "establishment"]
            })

          .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
            alert(result.geometry.bounds);
                alert(result.bounds);

          })
```

both the alerts show 'undefined' as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the map, you can do this:

```
var map = $("#textfield").geocomplete("map")
```

then you should be able to use

```
map.getBounds()
```

or any other built in google map api methods.

**Edit:** Found this in the downloaded script, there is an example 'Api'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `Map.getBounds()`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map). There isn't enough code in your question to tell why `result` may be `null`; if you can include some additional code, a link, or maybe set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it will allow everyone to take a deeper look.